# Two contract interactions same time?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft

So, i want to list my NFT, so, i update operators and then update my metadata.
The problem is i need to accept two times, one to update operators, other to update (list) in metadata. Is that a way to make the two interactions same time?
I already seen a marketplace with these feature, interacting with two contracts in the same transaction.
I have this question because user can accept the first operation and refuses the second one, or, when you accept the first and goes to accept the second one, will be fail if you got too fast, probably because the previous operation still registering.

Answer (score 0):

If those two operations are done by a smart contract they are part of the same transaction.

If they are both initiated by a tz address (an implicit account) you can bundle them in the same transaction with a wallet that has this feature.

I think umami wallet can do batches, probably other wallets can do that to.